# Collections examples

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

**Всем привет!**

Объясните начинающему практическое применение коллекций в Java

```
List: ArrayList,LinkedList,Vector,Stack  
 Set: HashSet,TreeSet,SortedSet
 Map: HashMap,TreeMap,SortedMap,Hashtable
```

*P.S.*

Желательно без ссылок на оракл, а на конкретно-рабочем применении
Спасибо!!

Comment: А вам не кажется, что собирать в одном вопросе разбор 11 разных структур - это несколько чересчур? И пробовали ли вы искать информацию про каждую структуру не только в официальной документации?

Comment: Скачайте любую книгу по Java на русском - там все будет написано.

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев что же вы такое говорите-то?! Это же читать надо! Страниц 50-100 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` - список.

`ArrayList` - список на основе массива. [Отличия между массивом и ArrayList.](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/03/difference-between-array-and-arraylist-in-java-example.html) Практическое использование... Ну например если вам нужен "массив" переменной длины.

`LinkedList` - связанный список. Суть в том, что каждый элемент хранит ссылку на следующий и предыдущий элементы списка. На практике, например хранить маршрут точка1->точка2->точка3->... и бегать по нему туда-сюда.

`Vector` - собственно вектор. То же самое, что и ArrayList, но потокобезопасный. Использовать так же.

`Stack` - стек. Практически используется для организации, СЮРПРИЗ, стека. Последним положил - первым взял.

`Set` - набор. Общая суть в том, что в нем не может быть одинаковых элементов. используется тогда, когда вам нужно хранить набор уникальных объектов.

`HashSet,TreeSet,SortedSet` - по большому счету отличаются только порядком хранения элементов.

`Map` - отображение. Простыми словами можно сказать, что это эдакий аналог "ассоциативного массива". Т.е. хранит пары ключ=>значение. Ключи уникальны, значения нет. Практических примеров использования - целый интернет.

`HashMap,TreeMap,SortedMap,Hashtable` - также как и в случае с Set, отличаются порядком хранения элементов.